# How to connect Laravel to MAMP mysql on Mac

Tags: php, laravel, mamp

Here is my `Laravel` Database config

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=8889
DB_DATABASE=carnet
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

But i keep getting this error

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
>   (using password: YES)

Comment: Are you sure `8889` is the correct port?

Comment: Yes i've used the same port 8889 to connect on my MySQL Workbench and it connected successfully.

Comment: I guess username password is not correct

Comment: Can you post what `config/database.php` file has? is it picking up values from `.env` file?

Comment: 'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '8889'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'carnet'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'root'),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],

Comment: Some people don't use password in local machine.  Are you one of those?

Comment: They are all the same .env and config/database.php i.e

Comment: Did you not mispell the schema name? (carnet)

Comment: i do use a password, a default password i.e

Comment: nope i did not.

Comment: Did you tried without password ?

Comment: Don't forget to restart the server after each change in the `.env` file

Comment: yes and without password i get "SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'carnet'

Comment: Dumb question, but have you created the Schema?

Comment: haha yes i have

Comment: Try without password, usually in windows Xampp there is no default password. But Mac this wouldn't be the case......

Comment: Please post how you managed to solve it, for future reference

Comment: I simply restarted my machine. how lame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the host from **localhost** to **127.0.0.1** and check if it connects.

Comment: you may want to try this, usually this is my fix whenever I encounter this error.